# Log4j configuration for session variables

Tags: log4j

Need log4j configuration for session variables.

Assume i have 3 variables - session id, user name, user id, company id

I want all these variables to be printed in the log with date and logger severity.

How to configure it to print all the above values ?

Thanks.

Comment: I will be helpful if you can explain what you have tried and what errors you got.

Comment: i am not sure how to put the session variable in the log4j..will it automatically comes...How to configure it...Do we need to do any coding for it

Comment: You should not log session id as it could allow someone with access to the logs to usurpate the user session

Answer (score 0):

They suggest to use MDC which is a feature of both log4j 1.X and 2 for things like that.

MDC is something like a Map that uses Java ThreadLocal construct and provides static put() and get() methods - therefore it is effectively thread-safe, but it should be cleared after use.

I.e. as I understand this - since in a servlet environment threads are managed by some kind of a thread pool, when a web server request is processed, some thread is assigned to the processing - when a request is done processing this thread is freed and might be assigned to a next request - so before that it is crucial that MDC gets cleared - or at least, its contents are reassigned during the start of the processing of each request.

They suggest that the best pattern to do this is using a standard J2EE request filter.
E.g. in the servlet filter:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession ses = req.getSession(false);
        
        if (ses != null) {
            String userId = (String)ses.getAttribute("userId");
            if (userId != null) {
                MDC.put("userId", userId);
            }
        }
        
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
        MDC.remove("userId");
    }
}
```

And then in log4j.properties configuration file:

```
...
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-20X{userId} %5p %t %c{2} %m%n
...
```

I got this information from [here](https://blog.oio.de/2010/11/09/logging-additional-information-like-sessionid-in-every-log4j-message/), which points also to [here](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/). I can confirm that this works with log4j 1.2 that I am using with an old OC4J server.